# Trying to differentiate white of roads, from the white of mountain tops. Need help tuning out the white of mountain tops

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a roadmap that I generated from ARCGIS using slope, the problem is some tops of mountains are also flat, so they are being classified as roads (white). Therefore when using the image as a mask in Unreal Engine, material is being applied to the wrong places. Is there a tool or method in photoshop to select or get the roads only?

[image]
The solid white lines are the roads, the spotty sections are tops of mountains which we don't want

Comment: Like a.. `select road tool`..? %) How PS would distinguish white pixels from other white pixels? I’d try to see if there are any other maps available to you that could help: maybe a height map that you can use to mask out roads that should be on lower altitude

Comment: Manually paint black over the mountains to remove the white in those areas. There's no way Photoshop can determine *this* white is a mountain and *that* white is a road.